# Using eval to print an array value

Tags: php, arrays, eval

```
$cars = array
  (
  array("Volvo",22,18),
  array("BMW",15,13),
  array("Saab",5,2),
  array("Land Rover",17,15)
  );

$key = '[1][0]';
$str = '$cars'.$key;
echo $str."\n";
eval($str);
```

Output:

```
$cars[1][0]
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in ... : eval()'d code on line 1
```

I'm expecting it to print the value, i.e `BMW`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the obvious "[when is eval evil in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php)", which I assume you know.

For your error there's multiple reasons. First of all, the code you're executing is the following (which you know as you're printing it):

```
$cars[0][1]
```

Just like this wouldn't do anything in raw PHP (`<?php $foo; ?>`) it also does nothing in the `eval` statement (I've added an `echo` in my code to fix this). Secondly, you're forgetting the semicolon at the end of the statement (as with any PHP).

The correct statement would therefore look like this:

```
<?php

$cars = array
  (
  array("Volvo",22,18),
  array("BMW",15,13),
  array("Saab",5,2),
  array("Land Rover",17,15)
  );

$key = '[1][0]';
$str = 'echo $cars' .$key . ';'; // "echo $cars[0][1];"
echo $str."\n";
eval($str); // will echo "BMW"
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/283946)

If you'd rather have the value returned into a variable, use `return`:

```
<?php

$cars = array
  (
  array("Volvo",22,18),
  array("BMW",15,13),
  array("Saab",5,2),
  array("Land Rover",17,15)
  );

$key = '[1][0]';
$str = 'return $cars' .$key . ';'; // "return $cars[0][1];"
echo $str."\n";
$var = eval($str);
var_dump($var); //string(3) "BMW"
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/283948)

Comment: To sum it up, `eval` evaluates _statements_, not _expressions_ as OP's thinking.

Comment: @georg Absolutely. That's a great way of putting it.

Comment: Yes, indeed I was thinking it evaluated expressions. The example on the PHP manual is not clear.